# .jar will not find internal resource images but compiled program does

Tags: java, javax.imageio, resource-loading

I've been trying to load some pictures to use in my Swing UI and while my compiled program will load the images correctly, **my .jar does not find the images**.

First of all, I've marked my resource file as "Resource Root". The project layout looks like this:

[image: project layout shown.Outside of the source folder, there is the resource folder, and inside it an images folder with the resources in question.]

The compilation output layout looks like this:

[image]

The .jar layout looks like this:

[image]

Now, the code that's been loading the pictures is inside the *gui* package; here it is:

```
        try {
            System.out.println(this.getClass().getResource("../images/buttonClip.png").getPath());
            attchmntBtnImg = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("../images/buttonClip.png"));
            sendMsgBtnImg  = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("../images/buttonForward.png"));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The print line output prints correctly the path of the picture

```
/C:/Users/path/to/Project/out/production/Peer2Party_desktop/images/buttonClip.png
```

While there are no errors when running it from intellij idea, the artifact generated (if I run it from the cmd, with or without administrator priviledges) gives me a NullPointerException at the System.out.println(), but, undoubtedly, that's not the cause of the error, since it'll still crash on the next line even if I remove the println.

[image]

I've tried to do these in order to load the images, to no avail:

```
this.getClass().getResource("/../images/buttonClip.png");
getClass().getResource("/../images/buttonClip.png");
```

```
this.getClass().getResource("images/buttonClip.png");
getClass().getResource("images/buttonClip.png");
```

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/buttonClip.png");
getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/buttonClip.png");
```

Any help is very VERY welcome.

***Important note:*** I'm on windows 10, the pictures are inside the correct path(file.jar/images/buttonClip.png), but at runtime the .class won't find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use

```
this.getClass().getResource("/images/buttonclip.png");
```

it looks for the file from project root directory

Comment: Oh, my, god. Holy cow. Thank you. What the heck, I think I tried this already, but probably not exactly this. Thank you ALOT!